# Rails record where at least one association with attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, rails-activerecord

I have a model `Purchase` which `has_many` `products`. I want to pull all the `purchases` which have at least one `product` which has been fully paid for.

`Product` has a `status` where `status 4` means it has been fully paid.

I tried defining a scope in the `Purchase` model:

```
scope :full_paid, -> {
  joins(:products).where(products: { status: 4 })
}
```

But this only pulls purchases for which all the existing `products` are fully paid. Can I instead pull all the purchases which have at least 1 fully paid product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so:

1) Use `left_outer_joins` with count as below:

```
scope :full_paid, -> {
  left_outer_joins(:products)
      .select("purchase_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN products.status= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as paid")
      .having("paid > 0")
      .group("products.purchase_id")
}
```

2) Similar to *@John Skiles Skinner* answer but with some changes, add **group** to get *unique purchases* from the **DB side**:

```
Product.select(:purchase_id).where(status: 4).group(:purchase_id)
```

I think there may be other ways as well

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it, though I'm not sure it's the best way:

```
Product.where(status: 4).map{|prod| prod.purchase}.uniq
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I accepted the other answer because that seemed more efficient to me, thanks once again :)

Comment: and also, using ruby inside an active record query it's not recommended because of the optimisation that is done when you use only active record rules. imagine if you have many Products, this line can turn the things much more slow.